# Selected drop box value not changing the another field value in laravel 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

I want to set the hidden input field value to selected drop box value. Here is my hidden field code and drop box code.

```
 {!! Form::hidden('color') !!}


 {!! Form::select('type', array('type' => 'type','Orange' => 'Orange', 'Red' => 'Red','Green' => 'Green'), 'type') !!}
```

Below is my jquery.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#type').on('change',function(){
        $('#color').val($(this).val());

    });

});
```

But as the hidden field value it will not set the value. Why is that?

Comment: I'd recommend removing the laravel tag, it's not related to your problem. Instead, can you show us the *rendered* HTML?

Comment: I don't see a hidden input there

Comment: <input name="color" type="hidden">

Comment: Is this before or after your script tag?

Comment: script is after the form/that

Answer (score 1):

aYou are referencing an element whose ID is "type", but you don't have any.

Add the type ID to your select box.

---

Try this:

```
{!! Form::hidden('type', null, array('id' => 'color')); !!}

{!! Form::select('type', array(
    'type'   => 'type',
    'Orange' => 'Orange',
    'Red'    => 'Red',
    'Green'  => 'Green'
), 'type', array(
    'id' => 'type'
)) !!}
```

---

#### [Laravel 5 FormBuilder  API Documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.html)

#### [Further reading](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html#form-model-binding)

Comment: I have updated the script above. How to add an id for the select box in laravel 5?

Comment: Updated the answer with sample script

Comment: Still not done. Then how to change the hidden field with id in laravel?

Comment: No, I changed the {!! Form::hidden('color', ['id' => 'color']); !!} to {!! Form::hidden('color', ' ', ['id' => 'color']); !!} also. But still color field get empty

Comment: [Check this out.](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/157/creating-a-hidden-input-field) Your code should work. I adjusted the answer now to use the `array()` function instead of the `[]` literal. See if that helps

Comment: But really please have your *rendered* HTML in your answer. That is very important to determine what is wrong with your attempt